# Is it possible to have the kineticjs stage overflow its parent div

Tags: kineticjs

Is it possible to have the canvas overflow its parent `kineticjs-content` div?

I have tried to set `overflow: visible` in every possible parent div, but stage content is still cropped to the div size.

Comment: My current use case is having a big canvas within a smaller parent div. The parent div should be scroll- and pannable. Content of the canvas has to be visible outside the scroll area.

Answer (score 0):

No.

KineticJS draws using a canvas element and the canvas element will clip any drawing outside its boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a solution with the help of markE's reply.

It is possible to overflow divs: the canvas has to be bigger than the parent div.

Here is a basic jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/LhpPf/1/

```
<div  style="position: absolute; left:100px; width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid #000000; overflow: visible;">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="200" style="position: absolute; left:-50px;"></canvas>
```